# Facebook PHP Get User information in Page Tab, getUser returns 0 after redirect to login

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, permissions

I am trying to create a competition entry which checks to see if the user likes a page before entering. If they do, it will fetch their name, email and birthday for the competition entry details.

For some reason however, I cannot get my PHP code to work.

```
    <?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';

    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXX',
  'cooke' => true
));

// Get User ID

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $me = $facebook->api('/me?fields=likes.target_id(215359398497970),birthday,first_name,last_name,email');
    if($me){
        $first_name = $me['first_name'];
        $last_name = $me['last_name'];
        $email = $me['email'];
        $dob = $me['birthday'];
        die($me);
    } else {
        $likes = false;
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    die($e);
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  //echo $loginUrl;
}
?>
```

For some reason, it gets stuck in a redirect loop because the loginURL doesn't seem to log my user in.

Comment: `/me/first_name` is not the correct syntax to access a user’s first name (same for last_name, birthday and email) – so your API calls fail, cause an exception – and in catching that you are setting `$user` to null yourself … and that triggers displaying the login URL again.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me Insinuates that I am using the correct syntax

Comment: `/me` alone will deliver all that data (expect the likes, of course), you just have to pull it out of the data structure. (And you can include the likes-data if you specify it via the `fields`parameter.) Btw., hasn’t it occurred to you that making a separate API call for each value would mean multiple time-consuming HTTP requests …?

Comment: Okay, but for now I cannot access that information because getUser is always returning 0.

Comment: There’s _lots_ of questions dealing with that specifically here already, so please do some research.

Comment: I've been doing research for around 2 hours. I cam't find a solution to my problem. I wouldn't create a question on SO if I knew it was already answered.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to go through all the debugging steps and possible causes that have been discussed over and over here already with you again.

Comment: Even the facebook SDK example in GitHUB does not work for my app id and secret.

Comment: Well, it is affected by the same possible set of problems (the most likely one is sessions not working correctly because cookies are refused).

Comment: I have it now so it goes to "Go to app" to authenticate the application. After it redirects, it still returns 0 for getUser. Any idea why? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's still looking. This is how I fixed my problem. I had to ensure that theis code was executed BEFORE any other code so I plonked it to the very top of my php file and it worked. I think the problem was that the headers had already been sent but I was unaware because my PHP warnings / errors are not enabled to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. I used an example project, and couldn't figure out why it keeps returning 0. tried nearly all related links here but none solved it.

The solution was to update Facebook's SDK files in the example project.
Simple and easily missed,